# Problem with Java Applet

Tags: java

I'm new to Java `Applet`s. I have a problem while reloading the applet. When I resize the applet window or open some other application and then come back to the applet, the contents on the screen is redrawn. Basically my `paint` method is getting called. I want the contents of the `paint` method to be called only once. How can I accomplish this? Can anyone please help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You are misunderstanding how `paint` works - you have no real control over how many times it is called. What are you doing in the `paint` method that makes you think you only want to do it once and why is it a problem that it gets called again?

If you're worrying about flickering, then you might like to look at painting into a *buffer*. Code not directly related to painting should *not* be in the `paint` method. You can put other initialization logic in the applet's `start` method

Answer (score 0):

If you're putting initialization code into the paint method, you might think about putting it into the init or start methods instead.

The phrase you'd be looking for is [applet lifecycle](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/applet/lifeCycle.html).

Answer (score 0):

I am new to java applet design and when running it i get one problem that says "no main"

here is my code:

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class abhidev extends Applet {

    /** Initializes the applet abhidev */
    public void init() {
        try {
            setBackground(Color.cyan);

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        try{
            g.drawString("this ais an applet window",10,30);
            showStatus("this is astatus window");
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The applet class name is: abhidev.java.

Comment: This looks like a separate issue. Please post it as its own question by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)
 button.